# Nvidia Persistance Daemon failed to start with drivers 390.xx

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

[image: Screenshot]

I am currently using 384.111 drivers, which work just fine. However, I tried upgrading to 390.12 initially, which caused this error, and 390.25 does too. I suspect 390.42 will have the same issue. I've installed both from the `.run` on Nvidia's website and the `nvidia-384` package.

So, whenever I start up a 390.xx driver from the `Ubuntu` grub option, it loads with the regular splash screen and then into tty1, except it starts blinking; as in, the screen turns off and then on again. While the screen is off, none of my keystrokes are registered, meaning I have to spam a key a couple times for it to show up. This also makes it impossible to enter my password as I cannot see if a keystroke has been registered.

The thing is, when I select the `Advanced options for Ubuntu` grub option and then select recovery mode and then `Resume`, it boots normally into gdm3 and I can use the system as per usual.

I tried booting into `Ubuntu` and then pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> to show tty1, and saw what's in the screenshot.

#### Specs

- Ubuntu 16.04
- 4.13.0-37-generic
- GTX 1060 6GB

Answer (score 5):

I would disable the nvidia-persistenced daemon. It's really meant for GPU server applications using CUDA, where there isn't an X server running. All it does is open the GPU device and hold it open. The GPU takes a couple seconds to initialize, so the persistence daemon is useful for running lots of short-duration CUDA jobs. On a desktop machine, the X server will hold open the GPU device, so nvidia-persistenced doesn't have any benefit.

That said, it sounds like you may still be having general GPU driver issues. I don't think it would hurt to try the 390.42 version -- there seem to be a number of bugs recently, but hopefully Nvidia is working on fixing them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will try that and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this issue that's been working for me for a couple of weeks now.

Simply set grub to **text** mode, add the following line to grub and update it:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text
```

Hope it helps

PS: disabling nvidia-persistance did not work for me